# Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS installer crashing with secondary drive plugged in via USB

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, hard-drive, uefi

I have a laptop with a completely unreadable LCD panel but completely functioning internals. I had previously tried to install Ubuntu server directly onto the device using an HDMI display but UEFI did not show up on the display. I removed the SATA HDD from the device and tried to use a USB-SATA cable to install Ubuntu server onto the hard drive by having a secondary laptop boot into the installer and selecting the USB hard drive as the destination of the install. The installer crashes whenever I plug in the USB HDD.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention release (*you've hidden that in the title that's now always visible when questions are read*) and haven't ruled out ISO validation issues (*did you verify it?*) or other issues. An OS cannot overrule a machines firmware (*ie. UEFI is firmware*) and I'd use another box to perform that given screen issues on this device.  I've used boxes with bad screens before in QA, but how easy/difficult they are will always depend on device (*and its firmware more so than the OS itself*).

Comment: @guiverc thank you for your response. ISO was validated. The installer crashes as soon as I plug in the HDD via USB. I tried an SSD as well and the installer still crashed. The installer works fine when the secondary drive is not plugged in. The Installer version is 23.04.2 and the Ubuntu release is 22.04.2 LTS.